# Regular expression in Search Sharepoint 2013

Tags: search, regex

I' having problems with using a regular expression in Sharepoint 2013 Search. I insert it into a crawl rule and checked `Use regular expression syntax for matching this rule`.

I validated my regex on page `regex101` so I am 100% sure it is correct.

```
^(https?:\/\/)([\da-zA-z\.]+)\/([\da-zA-z]+)$
```

This is the firsts of the crawl rules and I select `Exclude`, but pages are still searchable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you performed an index reset and a full crawl after adding the rule to put it in place with no time delay?

Comment: I tried but event Test in Craw Rules says: no rules match this URL.
Test URL:
https://google.com/pager

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is based on this:

> **Protocol part**
>
> Regular expression operators cannot be used in the protocol part of the URL. This means, for example, the following RegEx rule cannot be created:
>
> ```
> .*//www.microsoft.com/.*
> ```
>
> If you try to create a rule like this, the system will add `http://` in the beginning and thus make `“.*”` as the second part of the URL. The resulting rule in this case will be:
>
> ```
> http:// .*//www.microsoft.com/.*
> ```
>
> which may not be what you intended.

From [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/enterprisesearch/archive/2010/01/21/regular-expressions-support-in-crawl-rules.aspx)